# Test with pregmatch

Tags: php, preg-match

I has this in sources to get:

```
preg_match('/([-\w]+).facebook.divisiondesproduitsprofessionnels.com/', $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"])
```

My script is located in `https://facebook.divisiondesproduitsprofessionnels.com/France/steampod/html/`.

I am surprised that this pregmatch doesn't return TRUE.  Can someone help?

Comment: Have you perhaps tried `echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]`?

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour Tim.

\w  Any word character (letter, number, underscore)
So you want more than one word character or dash, something, then facebook... remove the ([-\w]+) and it'll be fine.

A great tool to use is rubular.com .

Hope it helps,
Sincérement.